# JQuery to add item to Asp.Net PlaceHolder control

Tags: asp.net, jquery, controls, placeholder

It looks to me that the ASP.Net PlaceHolder control doesn't emit any HTML, and therefore can't be used by clientside javascript or JQuery to add items to the PlaceHolder.  Does anyone know of a way around this limitation, or of an ASP.Net control that can be used to dynamically add items by client side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is very true. Anyway, JavaScript cannot add controls to the PlaceHolder, only insert elements in its place.
You can use a client side `<div></div>`, or a `Panel` - they will all have the effect you're looking for.